# On the space of polynomials in $T$ (a linear operator) with no non-zero invariant subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, extension-field, invariant-subspace

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over a field $F$ and let $T: V\to V$ be a linear transformation. Assume that $T(W)$ is not a subspace of $W$ for every non-zero, proper subspace $W$ of $V$. Let $F[T]:=\{ p(T): V\to V | p(x)\in F[x]\}$.

I have three questions :

(1) How to show that $\ker p(T)=0$ for every $0\ne p(T)\in F[T]$ ?

(2) if (1) is true then every $0 \neq p(T)\in F[T]$ is an isomorphism. How to show that the inverse of every $0 \neq p(T)\in F[T]$ is again a polynomial in $T$ ? i.e. how to show that $F[T]$ is a field ?

(3)  How to show that $[F[T] : F]=\dim_F (V)$ ? i.e. how to show that $\dim_F F[T]=\dim_F V$ ?

Comment: Statement 1) is untrue as written.  For instance, if $T$ is the $90^\circ$ rotation in $\Bbb R^2$ then $T$ satisfies the conditions, but we have $\ker[p(T)] = \Bbb R^2$ when $p(x) = x^2 + 1$.  Presumably, we should specify "every **non-zero** $p(T) \in F[T]$"

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Never mind...

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: yes I did indeed meant non-zero $p(T)$ ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (1), it suffices to note that $\ker p(T)$ is an invariant subspace of $T$ (for any polynomial $p$).

For (2): Let $m(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $T$. Using condition (1), we conclude that $m(x)$ is irreducible (how?).  Consider an arbitrary polynomial $p(x)$. Since the gcd of $p$ of $m$ is $1$, there exist polynomials $f,g$ such that
$$
f(x) p(x) + g(x)m(x) = 1.
$$
Because $m(T) = 0$, we can deduce that $f(T)$ is the inverse of $p(T)$.

For (3): Note that $[F[T]:F]$ is the degree of $m$.  By the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, this is at most $\dim V$.  To show that it cannot be less than $\dim(V)$, note that for any non-zero $x \in V$, the $T$-invariant subspace generated by $x$ is a non-zero subspace of $V$ whose dimension is at most $\deg(m)$.